# Need regexp help to remove css code

Tags: regex

How could we use regexp (replace) to find all occurrences of the following CSS 
code in a long string and remove them (the XMP code is what I added)?   Thanks.

```
<xmp> 
body { font-family : "Courier New", Courier, monospace; font-size : 9pt; valign : top; text-align : left; line-height: 9pt } 

td { 
font-family : "Courier New", Courier, monospace; font-size : 9pt; valign : top; text-align : left; line-height: 9pt } 
</xmp>
```

Comment: Well, all these CSS code, and possibly dynamically generated javascript is from fedex incoming email, that is, in the BODY part of a fedex email.  None of the answers has been effective.  Someone must have handled a similar situation...  The python solution is closer in that at least it is deal with from server side language.

Comment: Don't assume that a regular expression is the way to solve a problem just because it involves text.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the string you provided is inside `myString` and all the css code is inside `cssString`.

```
cssString = cssString.replace(myString, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the "\\ \\" along with the content contained within it ! This is how you do in python:

```
s="<xmp> your css code</xmp>"
s=re.sub("<xmp>.*</xmp>", " ",s)
```

output:

```
>>>s
''
```

In the code above i am substituting everything that starts with  tag and $'.*' basically tells the python interpreter to include all the characters until the  end tag and substitutes the entire thing with $" ".

if you want to remove just the content of the tags then:

```
s="<xmp> your css code</xmp>"
code_inside_xmptag=re.search("<xmp>(*.)</xmp>",string)
s=re.sub(code_inside_xmptag.group(1)," ",string)
```

Output:

```
>>>s
<xmp> </xmp>
```

Over here i am basically searching for the  tags and creating a group for the content contained.
I am passing that as the string to be replaced/substituted.
You can read more about Regular Expressions in python : [Here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)